# How the db model should be for this scenario?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm modeling a database scenario but I'm not understanding properly how to achieve that. The scenario is a user that can make complaints online. He enters the title and the description of the complaint and submits the info. The site administrator can see all user complaints and answer. So I have a scenario like this:

```
User: Id, name
Admin: Id, name
Complaint: Id, Title, Description, Answer, Status (Waiting for resolution, Solved), IdUser, IdAdmin
```

And in terms of relationships there is:

```
1:N between User and Complaint
1:N between Admin and Complaint
```

This scenario should work for this example: The user submits a complaint, the Admin receives the complaint and submits the answer and the user can check the answer.

**Issue:**

However, the user then has access to the Admin answer and the user should be able to answer to that Admin answer similar to a chat scenario where then the admin will also have access to the new complaint message of the user. But I'm not understanding how the db model should be to support this scenario where can exist multiple messages between the user and admin related to a complaint. Do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Just as a side-note: please don't use tags in your post that are not relevant. This question is not related to PHP or MySQL after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a separate table for the messages.  It sounds like the messages are specific to a complaint, so you can have:

- `messageId`
- `complaintId` references `complaints(complaintId)`
- `byUserId` not-NULL when user initiates message
- `byAdminId` not-NULL when admin initiates message
- `messageText`

You may need to think through complicated scenarios.  Perhaps multiple admins are working one complaint (which the above model supports).  Or perhaps multiple complaints are combined into one message stream (which the above model does not support).

Comment: Good points. However, I wouldn't store the adminId and userId. Just the userId from the user, who send the message. As a complaint contains a unique user and admin, it is not necesarry to store that every time.

Comment: @davidev . . . That is very reasonable.  I was leaving the data model open to more interactions, in case that was desired.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple choices for solving this.
One option would be to restructure your compliant entity to make it usable as a an initial complaint and as an answer as well by adding an reference to a previous instance of compliant. This reference might be empty in case of an initial complaint or contains the id of an previous answer/complaint. The answer attribute would be obsolete in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your DB modelling is quiet good already.

> Complaint: Id, Title, Description, Answer, Status (Waiting for
>   resolution, Solved), IdUser, IdAdmin

As you explained, a complaint has a foreign key for the user and the admin. Now as every complaint has a unique id as primary key, you can identify every complaint.

I would suggest creating another table for messages

```
Message: Id, complaintId, message, date
```

Every message belongs to one complaints, but a complaint can have several messages, which is totally correct. If you want to display now every message from one complaint, wheather it's the admin or the user, you select all your messages from the specific complaint id.

```
SELECT message FROM message m WHERE m.complaintId = 1 ORDER BY m.date
```

Last, I suggest changing your admin table to just `Admin: Id`, where Id is the primary and foreign key. So, you basically save all  your users in user and set admins in the admin table.